# Declaring SYS_REFCURSOR and ROWTYPE in stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

So I have a stored procedure `ONE`

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ONE
(
   A in number
   B in number
   ...
   ZZ out SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
  SOME_OTHER_STUFF
BEGIN
   ...
END
```

This returns a sys_refcursor with some data I need. I then have a stored procedure `TWO`

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TWO
(
   A in number
   B in number
   ...
   ZZ out SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
     Count_Records Sys_Refcursor;
     l_rec Count_Records%rowtype;
BEGIN
    /* get some data from the ONE stored procedure to use on this procedure*/
    ONE(A,B,...Count_Records)

    Loop
       fetch count_records into l_rec;
       Exit When count_records%Notfound;
       If  l_rec.TT_RAW > MAX_RECORDS  Then
         Raise To_Many_Results;
       End If;
    End Loop;

END
```

I'm getting an error when I try to declare the rowtype `l_rec Count_Records%rowtype;`

How can I declare this variable? The problem is that `TT_RAW` which is the column I'm trying to get is a SUM and the cursor is not mapped to any table it includes a lot of calculation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch into a list of variables instead, or create your own record type:

```
...
fetch count_records into v_field1, v_field2, v_field3
...
```

Comment: Tried your method and it worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8):

The whole point of `sys_refcursor` is that it's dynamically defined. The `rowtype` declaration, on the other hand has to be static (if it's not, the compiler can't tell if the fields referenced from it are valid). This is the definition of a use case where you should be defining your own strongly typed ref cursor, instead of using `sys_refcursor`.

Below is a very simple example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY rc_example IS
   PROCEDURE two (a IN NUMBER, b IN NUMBER);
END rc_example;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY rc_example IS
   TYPE one_record IS RECORD (FIRST_VALUE VARCHAR2 (10));

   TYPE one_cursor IS REF CURSOR
      RETURN one_record;

   --Could alternately be declared using a table's rowtype:
   --TYPE one_cursor is ref cursor return some_table%rowtype;

   PROCEDURE one (a IN NUMBER, b IN NUMBER, zz OUT one_cursor) IS
   BEGIN
      OPEN zz FOR SELECT 'test' FROM DUAL;
   END one;

   PROCEDURE two (a IN NUMBER, b IN NUMBER) IS
      count_records SYS_REFCURSOR;
      l_rec count_records%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN
      one (a, b, count_records);

      LOOP
         FETCH count_records INTO l_rec;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_rec.FIRST_VALUE);
         EXIT WHEN count_records%NOTFOUND;
      END LOOP;
   END two;
END rc_example;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation and elaborate example. I used the method on the other answer which worked for me so I didn't had the chance to try yours, but will consider it next time I need to do a procedure like this. Best regards